# how to make donut to start from top in html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am making a donut chart with HTML canvas.

it has 550 different colors to display.

My question is: how to make sure that first color in array is displayed on top?

`lenArr` is array of `550` values. all values are "1"

`rgbArr` is array of `550` colors in hex codes.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("chart");
var chart = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawdountChart(canvas) {

  this.x, this.y, this.radius, this.lineWidth, this.strockStyle, this.from, this.to = null;
  this.set = function(x, y, radius, from, to, lineWidth, strockStyle) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    this.strockStyle = strockStyle;
  }

  this.draw = function(data) {
    canvas.beginPath();
    canvas.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
    canvas.strokeStyle = this.strockStyle;
    canvas.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, this.from, this.to);
    canvas.stroke();
    var numberOfParts = data.numberOfParts;
    var parts = data.parts.pt;
    var colors = data.colors.cs;
    var df = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfParts; i++) {
      canvas.beginPath();
      canvas.strokeStyle = colors[i];
      canvas.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, df, df + (Math.PI * 2) * (parts[i] / 100));
      canvas.stroke();
      df += (Math.PI * 2) * (parts[i] / 100);
    }
  }
}


var drawDount = new drawdountChart(chart);
drawDount.set(60, 60, 40, 0, Math.PI * 2, 40, "#000");
var data = {
  numberOfParts: 550,
  parts: { "pt": [20,20,20,20,20] }, //percentage of each parts 
  colors: { "cs": ["red", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "cyan"] } //color of each part
};
drawDount.draw(data);
```

```html
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the `from` parameter in your code for drawing the color arcs...
Below I simplified your code so it fits better in the snippet, as you can see I'm using the from as the initial value `var df = from;` and that is where the first color starts if you want it to start on top you can use:  `Math.PI*1.5` in my sample below I'm drawing multiple showing different values on the from.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("chart");
var chart = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawdountChart(canvas) {
  this.draw = function(x, y, radius, from, lineWidth, data) {
    canvas.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    var parts = data.parts.pt;
    var df = from;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.numberOfParts; i++) {
      canvas.beginPath();
      canvas.strokeStyle = data.colors.cs[i];
      canvas.arc(x, y, radius, df, df + (Math.PI * 2) * (parts[i] / 100));
      canvas.stroke();
      df += (Math.PI * 2) * (parts[i] / 100);
    }
  }
}

var data = {
  numberOfParts: 550,
  parts: { "pt": [20, 20, 20, 20, 20] }, //percentage of each parts 
  colors: { "cs": ["red", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "cyan"] }
};
var drawDount = new drawdountChart(chart);
drawDount.draw( 50, 60, 25,       0     , 40, data);
drawDount.draw(140, 60, 25, Math.PI     , 40, data);
drawDount.draw(230, 60, 25, Math.PI*1.5 , 40, data);
```

```html
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: thanks it is working

Comment: @RahulB if the answer was helpful don't forget to accept and +1, thanks